# Expression for chain rule of a geodesic equation solution

Tags: general-relativity, differentiation, geodesics

I'm doing some work on General Relativity and I found that there's an identity that -if true- would really simplify my calculations. I feel it has to be true but I haven't been able to prove it. It goes like this. Let's say we have a background metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and a solution to the geodesic equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2}\phi^\alpha(\lambda,x,\dot{x})+\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}\frac{d}{d\lambda}\phi^\mu(\lambda,x,\dot{x})\frac{d}{d\lambda}\phi^\nu(\lambda,x,\dot{x})=0
\end{equation}

$\phi^\mu(\lambda,x,\dot{x})$ determines the worldline parametrized by $\lambda$ that goes through point $x^\mu$ with velocity $\dot{x}^\mu$ at time $\lambda=0$. I'll use a dot to show derivation respect to $\lambda$ so that $\dot{\phi}(\lambda,x,\dot{x})=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\phi(\lambda,x,\dot{x})$ and

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\phi^\mu(0,x,\dot{x})&=x^\mu \\
\dot{\phi}^\mu(0,x,\dot{x})&=\dot{x}^\mu
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**The expression I want to prove is:**

\begin{equation}
\dot{\phi}^\mu(\lambda,x,\dot{x})= \frac{\partial \phi^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}\dot{x}^\nu+\frac{\partial \phi^\mu}{\partial \dot{x}^\nu}\ddot{x}^\nu
\end{equation}

where, obviously, $\ddot{x}^\mu = \ddot{\phi}^\mu(0,x,\dot{x})$. I have already checked that this is true for many examples involving logarithms, sines, exponentials, etc. So I feel it must be true, but I don't know how to prove it. Any ideas?

**An Attempt:**

If I define the inital conditions relative to some time $\lambda_0$. that is, if

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\phi^\mu(\lambda_0,x,\dot{x})&=x^\mu \\
\dot{\phi}^\mu(\lambda_0,x,\dot{x})&=\dot{x}^\mu
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
this means that basically what I want to prove is that

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\lambda} \phi^\mu\Big[\lambda,x(\lambda_0),\dot{x}(\lambda_0)\Big]=\frac{d}{d \lambda_0}\phi^\mu\Big[\lambda,x(\lambda_0),\dot{x}(\lambda_0)\Big]
\end{equation}

which maybe is an easier thing to prove using the time symmetries of geodesics.

Comment: perhaps i am wrong but if $\begin{aligned}\phi =\phi\left( \lambda ,x,\dfrac{dx}{d\lambda }\right) \\
\dfrac{d\phi }{d\lambda }=\dfrac{\partial \phi }{\partial x}\,\dfrac{dx}{d\lambda }+\dfrac{\partial \phi }{\partial \dot{x}}\,\dfrac{d}{d\lambda }\, \left( \dfrac{dx}{d\lambda }\right) +\dfrac{\partial \phi }{\partial \lambda }\end{aligned}$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, the thing is that $\phi$ is a function of $\lambda$ while $x$ and $\dot{x}$ are functions of $\lambda_0$ if you will, they are not functions of $\lambda$ so the usual chain rule doesn't work. With $\lambda_0$ I mean the reference value we use to set initial coordinates, which I set to zero in my question but could be $\lambda_0$.

Comment: I added an attempt I tried where I explain the difference between $\lambda$ and $\lambda_0$.